# joint or seperate optimizers when sharing weights between networks

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I am wondering, what are the side effects of these two scenarios.

1. `netA` and `netB` share weights but have one optimizer each
2. `netA` and `netB` share weights but use a single optimizer

The results are very similar, but not equal.

Consider this example

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

torch.manual_seed(0)

share_fc2 = True
batch_size = 4
channels = 2

training_data_A = torch.rand((batch_size, channels))
training_data_B = torch.rand((batch_size, channels))


class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    """Minimal network"""

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(channels, channels, bias=False)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(channels, channels, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.fc2(self.fc1(x))


netA = Net().requires_grad_()
netB = Net().requires_grad_()

if share_fc2:
    # replace fc2 by netA.fc2
    netB.fc2 = netA.fc2

lossA = netA(training_data_A).mean()
lossB = netA(training_data_A).mean()

lossA.backward()
lossB.backward()
```

#### Option 1

```py
# OPTION 1 (independent run, seed used)
optA = torch.optim.Adam(params=netA.parameters())  # contains shared fc2
optB = torch.optim.Adam(params=netB.parameters())  # conteins shared fc2
optA.step()
optB.step()

print(list(netA.parameters()))
print(list(netB.parameters()))
```

##### output

[image]

#### Option 2

```py
opt = torch.optim.Adam(
    params=(
        list(netA.parameters())  # contains netA.fc1, netA/B.fc2
        + list(netB.parameters())[:1]  # contains netA.fc1
    )
)
opt.step()
print(list(netA.parameters()))
print(list(netB.parameters()))
```

##### output

[image]

#### Questions

- are the differences due to Adam's internal parameter adjustments and thus can be ignored
- Are the differences due to mathematics in gradient calculation and application?
- Is one option better than the other?

Answer (score 0):

I added comments that helped me to better understand what happens here.

tldr: Option 2 (or 3) are preferred, as this does not apply the same gradient twice.

#### OPTION 1

```py
optA = torch.optim.Adam(params=netA.parameters())  # contains shared fc2
optB = torch.optim.Adam(params=netB.parameters())  # contains shared fc2
optA.step()  # applies 1 grad to fc1_A, 2 grads to fc2_AB
optB.step()  # applies 1 grad to fc1_B, 2 grads to fc2_AB
# applies the fc2_AB grads twice! Thus doubling the learning rate for fc2_AB
```

#### OPTION 2

```py
opt = torch.optim.Adam(
    params=(
        list(netA.parameters())  # contains netA.fc1, netA/B.fc2
        + list(netB.parameters())[:1]  # contains netA.fc1
    )
)
opt.step()  # applies 1 grad to fc1_A, 1 grad to fc1_B, 2 grads to fc2_AB
# does not double the learning rate for fc2_AB
```

#### OPTION 3

```py
optA = torch.optim.Adam(params=netA.parameters())  # contains shared fc2
optB = torch.optim.Adam(params=netB.parameters())  # contains shared fc2
optA.step()  # applies 1 grad to fc1_A, 2 grad to fc2_AB
optA.zero_grad()  # avoids the same gradient to be applied twice!
optB.step()  # applies 1 grad to fc1_B, 2 (ZERO!) grads to fc2_AB
# applies the fc2_AB grads twice! Thus doubling the learning rate for fc2_AB
```

Option 1 and 3 are identical and preferred, however, option 3 is slower as an unnecessary zero-gradient is applied.